type definition of mint in OpenCL seems to be wrong in MacOS
Consider the the following small script running with Mathematica 14.0.0 on Mac OS X ARM (64 bit) 14.4.1 (23E224)
In[155]:= src = "
__kernel void addTwo(__global mint* arry, mint len) {
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    if (index >= len) return; 
    arry[index] += 2;
}";

In[156]:= addTwo = 
 OpenCLFunctionLoad[src, "addTwo", {{_Integer}, _Integer}, 16]

Out[156]= OpenCLFunction["<>", "addTwo", {{_Integer}, "Integer64"}]

In[157]:= addTwo[ ConstantArray[1, 10], 10]

Out[157]= {{8589934595, 8589934595, 8589934595, 8589934595, 
  8589934595, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

The result is wrong !
Substituting mint with long gives the right result as you can see in the following strip
In[158]:= src = "
__kernel void addTwobis(__global long* arry, mint len) {
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    if (index >= len) return; 
    arry[index] += 2;
}";

In[161]:= addTwobis = 
 OpenCLFunctionLoad[src, "addTwobis", {{_Integer}, _Integer}, 16]

Out[161]= OpenCLFunction["<>", "addTwobis", {{_Integer}, "Integer64"}]

In[162]:= addTwobis[ ConstantArray[1, 10], 10]

Out[162]= {{3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}}

I believe that the #typedef directive for mint is incorrect for this specific machine target. As anyone has an idea where (.h file ...) mint type is defined an how implement the correct type fpr MacOs target.

You need to put any typedef for custom data type names in the OpenCL kernel into the OpenCL C code itself:
In[155]:= src = "
typedef int mint;
__kernel void addTwo(__global mint* arry, mint len) {
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    if (index >= len) return; 
    arry[index] += 2;
}";


Sure it's a solution, but my concern is where in the mathematica eco-system the type mint is defined ...

The compiler is called with the option -Dmint = int. A way to solve the problem is to call OpenCLFunctionLoad using an other definition for mint :
addTwo = OpenCLFunctionLoad[src, "addTwo", {{_Integer}, _Integer}, 16, "Defines" -> {"mint" -> "long"}]

